# Packaging Bokeh with py2exe

Tags: matplotlib, py2exe, bokeh

I've got an python application that generates charts using BOKEH (0.12), the charts are all standalone (i.e BOKEHJS gets inlined) so that there's no need for the browser to go onto the web to find the CDN or make any external connections.
It all works fine when I am running it from Eclipse, chart displays no problem. But when I try to package it with py2exe, the html file is created but no chart is shown when I open it in browser. This is what my setup.py looks like

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os
import psutil
import pkg_resources
import inspect
import matplotlib
import sys
import bokeh.core
import zipfile
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

includes=["sqlite3","PyQt4","decimal","bokeh.core","jinja2","matplotlib","mpl_toolkits","matplotlib.backends.backend_wx","bokeh"]
excludes=[]
packages=["pkg_resources"]
dll_excludes=['libgdk-win32-1.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll', 'msvcp90.dll','msvcr71.dll', 'IPHLPAPI.DLL', 'NSI.dll',  'WINNSI.DLL',  'WTSAPI32.dll']


dir_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) # script directory
parent_dir_name=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_name,os.pardir))
iconfile_config_location = "my_icon.ico"
configuration_location = "my_configuration.ini"
database_location = "localDB"
datafiles = [('', [configuration_location,database_location])]
datafiles.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dist_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, "release")



setup(

      options={"py2exe": {"compressed": 2,
                          "optimize": 0,#string or int of optimization level (0, 1, or 2) 0 = do not optimize (generate .pyc) 1 = normal optimization (like python -O) 2 = extra optimization (like python -OO)
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 2,
                          "dist_dir": "release",
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                          }
               },
      windows=[{"script":"main.py","icon_resources": [(1, iconfile_config_location)],}],
      data_files= datafiles

      )

# Add boke/core/_templates files to the library.zip file
bokeh_path = sys.modules['bokeh.core'].__path__[0]
zipfile_path = os.path.join(dist_dir, "library.zip")
z = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile_path, 'a')
for dirpath,dirs,files in os.walk(os.path.join(bokeh_path, '_templates')):
    for f in files:

        fn = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        z.write(fn, os.path.join(dirpath[dirpath.index('bokeh'):], f))
z.close()
```

Can anyone guide me on how to package Bokeh so that the resulting executable can make use of it. (i.e everything gets bundled in together) is it possible?

I also noticed that when I set the optimize option to 2, it doesn't work, I get the error

```
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "bokeh\plotting\__init__.pyo", line 2, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "bokeh\document.pyo", line 36, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "bokeh\model.pyo", line 12, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "bokeh\core\properties.pyo", line 73, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "bokeh\core\enums.pyo", line 25, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "bokeh\icons.pyo", line 78, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Any ideas

Comment: Is there any relevant output in your browser's javascript console log?

Comment: Ahh thanks, looking at the file using the debug tools in IE, I see ReferenceError: 'Bokeh' is undefined.
I also did a diff between a working one (generated directly from Eclipse, just running the main.py) and the executable main.exe, and the difference I can see is that bokeh.min.js and bokeh.min.css are missing, i.e. they are not being in-lined I suspect that its because my setup.py doesn't add them in....Any ideas on how I can get py2exe to include all the bits that are needed.

Comment: That's definitely the problem on the Bokeh side then, but I'm afraid I've never used `py2exe` so I can't help with how to configure it. `setup.py` files have a notion of "extra" files that can be explicitly noted for installation, maybe `py2exe` has something similar.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot appreciate it, do you know of another way to create windows executable that has worked well with bokeh?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't have any experience with any python .exe things